# Haskell: get table count(*) with postgresql.simple (with Connection Pool)

Tags: postgresql, haskell, connection-pooling

Please,.. how can I get count(*) from one table? I'm trying to connect some fragments of code,..but so far no success.

This is what I have:

```
fetchSimple :: FromRow r => Pool Connection -> Query -> IO [r]
fetchSimple pool sql = withResource pool retrieve
   where retrieve conn = query_ conn sql 

getUsersCount :: Pool Connection -> IO (Int)
getUsersCount pool = do
   res <- fetchSimple pool "SELECT count(*) FROM article" :: IO [Int]
   let f = head res
   return f
```

this gives me following error:

```
No instance for (FromRow Int) arising from a use of ‘fetchSimple’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  res <- fetchSimple pool "SELECT count(*) FROM article" :: IO [Int]
In the expression:
  do { res <- fetchSimple pool "SELECT count(*) FROM article" ::
                IO [Int];
       let f = head res;
       return f }
In an equation for ‘getUsersCount’:
    getUsersCount pool
      = do { res <- fetchSimple pool "SELECT count(*) FROM article" ::
                      IO [Int];
             let f = ...;
             return f }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to extract a single value, you don't do so directly. You wrap it in an [Only](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.1.2/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#t:Only).

So try the annotation `:: IO [Only Int]`